# How to delete all the documents containing a particular field in an index with delete_by_query api?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete all the documents which contain a specific field, from an elasticsearch index using delete_by_query API.

```
doc.key_in_question: dummy_data_score:1
```

I am trying to delete all the documents which contain the key `doc.key_in_question` in them.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using the following should achieve what you want

```
POST index/_delete_by_query?q=_exists_:doc.key_in_question
```